# How to implement Amazon S3 Intelligent Tiering API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to Enable the Amazon S3 intelligent tiering on my platform during object upload, but since the uploads would be done by random users and not myself, i want to know if there's an existing documentation or API to implement to enable S3 intelligent tiering during object upload via my codebase.

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: Currently am using the standard S3 file upload API that enables me to just upload files to the S3 bucket without implementing the intelligent tiering. So am trying to figure out if there's an existing API for s3 intelligent tiering during file uploads